# How to show / hide component with onClick set on element from other component

Tags: reactjs

I'd like to show/hide one of the components when clicking on the element (icon ) from other components.

I know how to do it from the same component (when an element with onClick option is on the same component), but not sure how to refer to such option from other components.

I have Main.js component where I would like to hide  and show other components when clicking on a button from LeftMenu.

Main.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.css';
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';
import { Container, Row, Col, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Tiles from '../Tile/Tiles'
import Header from '../Navbar/Navbar'
{/* import Tile from '../Tile/Tile' */}

class Main extends Component {

  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
    this.state = { show: true };

    this.toggleDiv = this.toggleDiv.bind(this)
  }

  toggleDiv = () => {
    const { show } = this.state;
    this.setState({ show: !show })
  }

  render() {
    return (
          <div className="Main">
            {/* Background color set with Helmet */}
            <Helmet>
              <style>{'body { background-color: #1A2C3B; }'}</style>
            </Helmet>

            {/* Base Layout */}
             <div className="Container">
              <Row className="RowHeader">
              <Header  />
               </Row>
              <Row>
              { this.state.show && <Tiles /> }
              {/* <Tiles></Tiles> */}
            </Row>
          </div>
          </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Another component in which I would like to have onClick option:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import FaHome from 'react-icons/lib/fa/home';
import FaDropbox from 'react-icons/lib/fa/dropbox';
import logo from './logo.png';
import './LeftMenu.css';
import  toggleDiv  from '../Main/Main'

class LeftMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <div className="LeftMenu">
            {/* Base Layout */}
             <div className="LeftContainer">
              <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
              </Row> 
              <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                <div className="LeftIcon">
                  <FaHome/>
                </div>
              </Row> 
              <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                <div className="LeftIcon">
                <button onClick={ toggleDiv }><FaDropbox/></button>
                </div>
              </Row> 
            </div>
          </div> 
    );
  }
}

export default LeftMenu;
```

As a result, when click on FaDropbox icon, I would like to hide

```
<Tiles />
```

from Main.js and show

```
<AnotherComponent />
```

The code above is what I was trying, but it throws an error, I'm not sure how to properly call toggleDiv from the Main component. As I'm quite new to React, will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: In order to do that you have to pass the onclick function as props to the other component from Main component

Comment: If the LeftMenu is in the Header component, simply pass the function as prop to the Header which will pass it to the LeftMenu. `<Header onToggleDiv={toggleDiv} />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this one can help you!

```js
const LeftMenu = (props) => (
 <button onClick={props.toggleComponents}>LeftMenu</button>
);

const Tiles = () => <div>Tiles</div>;
const AnotherComponent = () => <div>AnotherComponent</div>;

class Main extends React.Component{
  state ={
    isShowTiles:true
  };
  
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
         <LeftMenu toggleComponents={this.toggleComponents}/>
         <div class="toggleArea">
         {
           this.state.isShowTiles
             ? <Tiles />
             : <AnotherComponent/>
         }
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  toggleComponents=()=>{
    this.setState({
     isShowTiles:!this.state.isShowTiles
    })
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.toggleArea{
margin:10px;
padding:10px;
border:5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In general this is what is needed, but it's adding me additional LeftMenu component into Main component which duplicates that component. What is needed now is to setup such functionality for FaDropbox icon in LeftMenu component.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the state at the parent of both Main and LeftMenu. This process is called lifting state up.

Suppose the parent of both Main and LeftMenu is ParentComponent.

So now inside the parent component if you maintain state you can pass that down as prop to main component and a prop onClick to LeftMenu Component like

```
<LeftMenu onClick={toggleVisibility}/>
<Main show={this.state.visible} />
```

Now the toggleVisibility function will be like

```
const toggleVisibility = () => {
  this.setState(prevState=>({visible: !prevState.visible}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use redux or use context api, this will help to share the values from one component to another.
context api:-
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0):

This is why there's usually some state management in React apps, be it Redux, MobX, Flux, ReactN or something else. The scope of telling you how to introduce state management into your app would be to big, so I offer a quick solution instead:

### Wrapper

So, the gist of this problem is to wrap both `Main` and `LeftMenu` with a wrapper component (let's call it `LayoutWrapper`) that will manage the `show/hide` state for them. It would look like follows:

```
class LayoutWrapper extends Component {
  constructor( props ) {
    super( props )
    this.state = { show: true };

    this.toggleDiv = this.toggleDiv.bind(this)
  }

  toggleDiv() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ show: !prevState.show }))
  }

  render() {
    ...(your other components)...

    <Main showTiles={show} toggleDiv={toggleDiv}>
    <LeftMenu showTiles={show} toggleDiv={toggleDiv}>

    ...(rest of the code)...
  }
}
```

So, in a nutshell, you are lifting the state a level up and then passing it down the component chain as props, together with a function that's able to change it.

I hope this helps :)

P.S.: But as I stated in the beginning, this would be a perfect example as to why use some state management library - the easiest one to go with would be ReactN - maybe you should [give it a try](https://github.com/CharlesStover/reactn)?